# Stitching vias in an SMPS design

Tags: pcb-design, via, stitching

Hi I'm using a 4 layer stackup for my SMPS design (~100 W) arranged as follows:

| Signal | GND | GND | Power |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |

I read that the inductance of stitching vias could potentially harm the switching nodes so it should be avoided but should I still place stitching vias in void areas away from switching nodes? If so should these via require a ground pour in the top and bottom plane or should just be placed without it?

Comment: You will be effectively wasting an entire layer by having to GNDs next to each other. Are you able to do all your routing on top layer?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a small form factor but still wanted access to the signal and power planes if needed

Comment: AC input? How about a bog standard signal+Vcc, GND, Vcc, signal+GND stackup and via stitching between them?

Comment: *I read that the inductance of stitching vias could potentially harm the switching nodes* <-- that doesn't make sense so maybe you can reveal where you read this. Add a schematic and show on that schematic where they would be positioned.

Comment: Note that inductances reduce in parallel.  You speak of vias plural, implying significant reduction may occur. What value of inductance is a concern for your circuit? Assign a number to it and compare.